# SQL the condition met in every case?

Tags: sql

I have an example table called food

```
item    id    date
apple   1     in-date
apple   1     in-date
banana  2     rotten
banana  2     in-date
lemon   3     in-date
lemon   3     in-date
```

I would like to write a query that returns only the item where everything is in date
ie apple and lemon should be returned.

I have,

```
select item
from food
where date = 'in-date';
```

However this will return `banana` too even though some are out of date.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: As an aside, it would be a good idea to not use 'date' for a column name. It is a reserved word.

Answer (score 7):

```
select distinct item
from food
where item not in (select item from food where date<>'in-date')
```

Or if your SQL supports `exists`

```
select distinct item
from food
where not exists (select item from food f where date<>'in-date' and f.item=food.item )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT item, SUM( CASE mydate WHEN 'in_date' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) as rotten
FROM food
GROUP BY item 
  HAVING rotten==0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
 select distinct item
 from food
 where not exists (select item from food f where date<>'in-date' and f.item=food.item )
```

Comment: This still will include bananas, as the WHERE clause filtered out the `rotten` row before the HAVING clause could be applied

Comment: @Dems:- Thanx for correcting me. I have just updated my answer!!